# Who to report bug about R error messages?

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I am trying to install a package and this is the output:

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/raffaele/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rgdal’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpVOG6hQ/downloaded_packages’


✔ Package 'rgdal' successfully installed.
Warning message:
In utils::install.packages("rgdal", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

I strongly believe that the

> Package 'rgdal' successfully installed

message does not reflect the truth.

Who can I report to have the message changed?

Comment: The maintainer(s) of the package.  Their contact details should be given in the package documentation.

Comment: Which package? `rgdal`? I think the error message is outputted by `install.packages`, not by `rgdal`

Comment: Yes.  `rgdal`.  You're right, the message is printed by `install.packages()`, but as a result of information supplied by `rgdal`.  So they're the people you need to tell, particularly as you get an earlier error about `gdal-config`...

Comment: Did you use `install.packages()` to install that?  That checkmark at the start of the message looks like something `devtools` would print.

Comment: @user2554330 RStudio says that the library is missing and has a button to install it. I believe it calls `install.packages` with `repo=cran.rstudio.com`?

Comment: You should see if the incorrect message appears when you call `install.packages("rgdal")` outside of RStudio.  If so, it's an R bug; if not, it's an RStudio bug.